# Python 3 Tuple of enum Equality always fails

Tags: python-3.x, enums, tuples, equality

I am building a small simulation of Rock, Paper and Scissors, I have a payoff function that
returns a tuple of numbers given two actions

```py
def payoff(act1, act2):  
    if act1, act2 == Action.ROCK, Action.PAPER:
        return -1, 1
    elif act1, act2 == Action.PAPER, Action.ROCK:
        return 1, -1
    elif act1, act2 == Action.PAPER, Action.SCISSORS:
        return -1, 1
    elif act1, act2 == Action.SCISSORS, Action.PAPER:
        return 1, -1
    elif act1, act2 == Action.SCISSORS, Action.ROCK:
        return -1, 1
    elif act1, act2 == Action.ROCK, Action.SCISSORS:
        return 1, -1
    else :
        return 0, 0
```

I sample two actions at random when given as parameters the equality always fails.

```py
action1 = random.sample([Action.ROCK,Action.PAPER,Action.SCISSORS],1)
action2 = random.sample([Action.ROCK,Action.PAPER,Action.SCISSORS],1)

# always returns (0,0)
payoff(action1,action2)
```

I am not sure if am doing the equality check properly, as you may notice I construct tuples on the fly using `(act1,act2)`

Comment: random.sample(...) returns a string.  Try `action1 = random.sample([Action.ROCK,Action.PAPER,Action.SCISSORS],1)[0]`

Comment: @Mike67:  I think you meant "returns a list".

Comment: Yes - Thank you - sample returns a _list_

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
action1 = random.sample([Action.ROCK,Action.PAPER,Action.SCISSORS],1)[0]
action2 = random.sample([Action.ROCK,Action.PAPER,Action.SCISSORS],1)[0]

# always returns (0,0)
payoff(action1,action2)
```

random.sample() return an python list